# Using normalize-string XPath function from SQL XML query?

Tags: sql, xpath, where-clause

is it possible to run an SQL query, with an XPath "where" clause, and to trim trailing spaces before the comparison ?

I have an SQL XML column, in which I have XML nodes with attributes which contain trailing spaces. I would like to find a given record, which has a specified attribute value - without the trailing spaces.

When I try, I get...

*"There is no function '{http://www.w3.org/2004/07/xpath-functions}:normalize-space()'"*

I have tried the following (query 1 works, query 2 doesn't). This is on SQL 2005.

```
declare @test table (data xml)
insert into @test values ('<thing xmlns="http://my.org.uk/Things" x="hello " />')

-- query 1
;with xmlnamespaces ('http://my.org.uk/Things' as ns0)
select * from @test where data.exist('ns0:thing[@x="hello "]') != 0

-- query 2
;with xmlnamespaces ('http://my.org.uk/Things' as ns0)
select * from @test where data.exist('ns0:thing[normalize-space(@x)="hello"]') != 0
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What SQL database are you using? Oracle? MS SQL? MySql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server also doesn't include the `replace()` function which allows regular expressions. You best bet is using `contains()` which should work for your searches (the nested substring problem won't exist when you are not using wildcards).

```
select * from @test where data.exist('ns0:thing[contains(@x, "hello")]') != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is SQL Server 2005/2008, with SQLXML 4.0 this function (`normalize`) is not supported.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172038.aspx) MSDN article for more detail.

I would suggest converting the XML to a string and use `RTRIM`, `LTRIM` and other string functions of SQL instead.

Comment: Thanks, Oded. It turns out that the value of my attribute "x" is always 6 characters, so I created a 6 character variable (char(6)) and compared the attribute with an "sql:variable" clause. Thanks.